# Google Dashboard - chartRangeFilter , how to know when slider controls move, then stop

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I can add an event handler to the ChartRangeFilter controlWrapper to find out when the sliders are moving:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', selectHandler);
```

and I have a handler for it:

```
function selectHandler(e){

    var state = control.getState();

    console.log(state);

    if (state != 'inProgress') {
            currentLeftSliderPos = control.getState().range.start;
            currentRightSliderPos = control.getState().range.end;

            console.log(currentLeftSliderPos);
            console.log(currentRightSliderPos);
    }
}
```

It's not working and I know why. `control.getstate()`returns an object and is not really what I want. I know there is a way to check if the sliders are 'inProgress', but I can't figure out from what I have read on how to do that. Or do I check the 'ready' status? I don't want to reload graph data until the slider has stopped because I have a large dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `inProgress` property on the argument sent to the event handler

it has the following properties...

```
{
  "inProgress": false,
  "startChanged": true,
  "endChanged": false
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawDashboard,
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
});

function drawDashboard() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2017, 6, 12), 9],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 13), 8],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 14), 10],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 15), 8],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 16), 22],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 17), 25],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 18), 24],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 19), 14],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 20), 12],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 21), 8],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 22), 9],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 23), 4]
  ]);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard')
  );

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'AreaChart',
    containerId: 'chart'
  });

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0
    }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', function (eventArgs) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'control is moving = ' + eventArgs.inProgress;
  });

  dashboard.bind(control, chart);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <div id="control"></div>
</div>
<div id="info"></div>
```